# NM clamp for cable fished into box

Tags: electrical

My house has mostly AC/BX wiring.  I have added a light to an existing lighting circuit and pulled #12 Romex into an existing metal box. Problem is, this box has no 1/2" or standard size knockouts. It has only the smaller AC knockouts.  I need a snap-in cable clamp to properly ensure my non-metallic insulation doesn't get cut on the metla box opening.

I feel like this would be a nornal request but the folks at home Depot looked at me like I was speaking a different language.  I did find some 3/8" push-in cable clamps but they still looked to big.

Thanks!

Comment: I looked again. There is definitely a 1/2" knockout in that box, but I chose to pull the cable through the BX knockout, don't ask me why. Anyways, does such a cable clamp/gland exist to properly do this?

Comment: So the Romex is already in and you want to fit a clamp without disconnecting and removing the wire? You might be able to enlarge the hole with tin snips and then fit in a two-part clamp, but I think you would find it easier to disconnect the Romex inside the box, pull it out, enlarge the hole enough to fit a cable clamp, then re-install the Romex.

Comment: Actually, I can disconnect the wire.  Problem is I can't remove the box without tearing out lots of drywall, so it has to be a snap in and not a two part clamp.

Comment: Old thread I know but this may help someone else. Look at this box at Home Depot. RACO
2-Gang Electrical Square Box with NMSC Clamps and Bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the comments, the real problem isn't the knockout, it's a clamp that will work with access only to the inside of the box.

Luckily, this is a solved problem.  There are plastic push-in NM connectors made to install inside the box, such as the Raco Insider:

[image: Raco Insider]

This will install in a standard 1/2" KO.

This is a very common problem, so connectors that will work with cables fished into boxes are available almost everywhere electrical supplies are sold.

Big box stores are basically self service, I am sure there are exceptions, but I wouldn't expect ANY technical expertise from the staff.  I've even seen egregious code violations in DIY videos on their official Youtube channels.

Comment: My local electrical supply house manager confessed to me that he regularly trolls big-box looking for anyone competent, and hires them away.  **Clerks who remain at Home Depot are the "rejects"**. Home Depot is good at pre-employment screening, so has done that job for him! Apparently that's SOP in the supply house game.  HD only really wants stock boys.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of 1/2" knockout plastic and metal snap ins.  What I was specifically looking for was this exact thing for an AC/BX knockout, which is much smaller.  I am thinking they just don't exist.