# Opened a cutout hole in a breaker panel where I don't have room for a wire clamp

Tags: electrical-panel

I don't know what was going through my head here, but I opened a one of the cutout holes in a breaker panel to run a wire. Then I helpfully drilled a hole in the wooden stud for the wire (the panel is flush mounted, e.g. screwed into studs.

I am not, in fact, going to run the wire this way - will come out the top of the panel and *then* go through the stud.

What can do I do patch this unused hole / what is required by code (in general terms? There's no room for me to screw in any kind of clamp, as it's right against the stud. I've thought about:

- Ignoring it
- Covering with HVAC mastic tape
- Cutting a small rectangle of sheet metal and screwing it in over the hole as a cover

I'm not looking for unnecessary work, but I'm also not looking for a superhighway for mice to get in and wreak havoc.

[image]

Comment: Just use an "inside the box" clamp, as seen here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/153851/18078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one of these [Knockout hole plugs](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-2-in-Knock-Out-Seals-4-Pack-26071/100191724?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060397-92700076247463580&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7uSkBhDGARIsAMCZNJttFqHBeDUylPg8d504YQ6mh4mmyO-DcHuDKZVrbkje1SiOTaTK1TwaAmVkEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).  They come in different sizes.
You may have to chip a little more wood away to "pop" it in, but it is the easiest option made for the issue you have.

Comment: I should have figured something would exist already! Thanks!